# Simple *Authoritative DNS Server* in Java

Tags: java, dns

Is there an already written Java DNS Server that only implements authoritative responses. I would like to take the source code and move it into a DNS server we will be developing that will use custom rule sets to decide what TTL to use and what IP address to publish.

The server will not be a caching server. It will only return authoritative results and only be published on the WHOIS record for the domains. It will never be called directly.

The server will have to publish MX records, A records and SPF/TXT records. The plan is to use DNS to assist in load balancing among gateway-servers on multiple locations (we are aware that DNS has a short reach in this area). Also it will cease to publish IP addesses of gateway-servers when they go down (on purpose or on accident) (granted, DNS will only be able to help during extended outages).

We will write the logic for all this ourselves.. but I would very much like to start with a DNS server that has been through a little testing instead of starting from scratch.

However, that is only feasible if what we copy from is simple enough. Otherwise,, it could turn out to be a waste of time

Comment: Did you implement anything at which we could have a look at?

Comment: No, I did not. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

George,

I guess what you need is a java library which implements DNS protocol.
Take a look at [dnsjava](http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/)

This is very good in terms of complete spec coverage of all types of records and class.

But the issue which you *might* face with a java based library is performance.
DNS servers would be expected to have a high throughput. But yes, you can solve that by throwing more hardware.

If performance *is* a concern for you , I would suggest to look into [unbound](http://unbound.net/)

Comment: As for performance: Immediate response is definitely what we are looking for. (less milliseconds is better) However, the number of DNS requests will not be large. I do not anticipate a single server possibly having more than one request a second at any time of the day except for coincidence. These are not dedicated DNS servers. These DNS servers are actually usually the same as the gateway-servers. We will not be able to simply return ones own IP address though. We want to always return a pair of IP addresses. I expect that Java will sufficiently fulfill our speed requirement.

Comment: Sure, java would be more than able to suffice your throughput requirement of around 1 request per second. We were able to extract close to 700 requests per second while evaluating dnsjava.

Comment: And, I guess, it should be possible to put caching dns servers in front of it, so you possibly retain performance and still have Java's flexibility.

Comment: @geekGod - Have you (succesfully) compiled unbound under windows? I have tried it several times but failed to succeed. Please let me know if it is even possible!

Comment: Not on windows, but compiled it on Linux! What is the problem that you are facing ?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/

Unfortunately, the documentation states "jnamed should not be used for production, and should probably not be used for testing.  If the above documentation is not enough,
please do not ask for more, because it really should not be used."

I'm not aware of any better alternatives, however.

Comment: dnsjava is licensed under BSD license. The doc mentioned by you applies to jnamed which is command line program shipped more as an example for using dnsjava.

Comment: yeah, you should always know what you are doing when you program such a thing. But I guess a read-ohly non-recursing auth dns server is quite simple and can't develop too much security holes.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at Eagle DNS:
http://www.unlogic.se/projects/eagledns

It's been around for a few years and it's quite well tested by now.